# Bootstrap - 50% background with normal container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got question. I want to make something like in examples:
 - one column with content + one column with background
 - two columns with content and one of them with background

Problem is - I'm using normal container, not fluid. Should I use separate DIVs for backgrounds and use absolute position? Being honest - I don't like this idea.

My current code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:50%;height:500px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Test Content col-lg-6</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam mauris quis arcu pretium, quis lacinia odio lobortis. Mauris a tellus turpis. Fusce pretium enim eget lorem sodales lacinia non sed metus. Donec quis varius enim. Phasellus vitae sapien congue, convallis justo eu, pharetra turpis. Sed a augue et nulla sodales aliquet. Aenean id nulla vitae odio tincidunt placerat. Etiam pharetra, lorem a sollicitudin ultricies, elit lectus vehicula lectus, ac molestie risus nibh quis velit. Sed accumsan aliquet orci eu commodo. Nam consectetur lacinia tempus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Test Content col-lg-6</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam mauris quis arcu pretium, quis lacinia odio lobortis. Mauris a tellus turpis. Fusce pretium enim eget lorem sodales lacinia non sed metus. Donec quis varius enim. Phasellus vitae sapien congue, convallis justo eu, pharetra turpis. Sed a augue et nulla sodales aliquet. Aenean id nulla vitae odio tincidunt placerat. Etiam pharetra, lorem a sollicitudin ultricies, elit lectus vehicula lectus, ac molestie risus nibh quis velit. Sed accumsan aliquet orci eu commodo. Nam consectetur lacinia tempus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Any ideas? Sorry for my english.**

[image: Example 1][image: Example 2]

Comment: show your code too..

Comment: The background is the img with the dog and is located in the upper right like in your sample .. ?

Comment: Upper left, yes. Is there a better solution than using absolute DIV?
What about second example?

Comment: I have post  an answer jope is useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep in row  i suggest this layout (no position absolute )

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
      <div id="my_background_img" class="col-lg-6"> <! --you can add your background  to  this div --  eventually using adn id and a ccs external styling> 
      </div> 
      <div vclass="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Test Content col-lg-6</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam mauris quis arcu pretium, quis lacinia odio lobortis. Mauris a tellus turpis. Fusce pretium enim eget lorem sodales lacinia non sed metus. Donec quis varius enim. Phasellus vitae sapien congue, convallis justo eu, pharetra turpis. Sed a augue et nulla sodales aliquet. Aenean id nulla vitae odio tincidunt placerat. Etiam pharetra, lorem a sollicitudin ultricies, elit lectus vehicula lectus, ac molestie risus nibh quis velit. Sed accumsan aliquet orci eu commodo. Nam consectetur lacinia tempus.</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end first row -->
    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Test Content col-lg-6</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam mauris quis arcu pretium, quis lacinia odio lobortis. Mauris a tellus turpis. Fusce pretium enim eget lorem sodales lacinia non sed metus. Donec quis varius enim. Phasellus vitae sapien congue, convallis justo eu, pharetra turpis. Sed a augue et nulla sodales aliquet. Aenean id nulla vitae odio tincidunt placerat. Etiam pharetra, lorem a sollicitudin ultricies, elit lectus vehicula lectus, ac molestie risus nibh quis velit. Sed accumsan aliquet orci eu commodo. Nam consectetur lacinia tempus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Test Content col-lg-6</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam mauris quis arcu pretium, quis lacinia odio lobortis. Mauris a tellus turpis. Fusce pretium enim eget lorem sodales lacinia non sed metus. Donec quis varius enim. Phasellus vitae sapien congue, convallis justo eu, pharetra turpis. Sed a augue et nulla sodales aliquet. Aenean id nulla vitae odio tincidunt placerat. Etiam pharetra, lorem a sollicitudin ultricies, elit lectus vehicula lectus, ac molestie risus nibh quis velit. Sed accumsan aliquet orci eu commodo. Nam consectetur lacinia tempus.</p>
        </div>       
    </div> <!-- end second row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but row is 1170px and in the example the background is positioned to the left outside the container. Making this inside the row is not a problem for me.

Comment: I think in this way you get a more ordered (and fluid) solution .. you can also easily manage col-md and other if you need without the problem of fixed position ... In you last comment you need some other support  .. if so please explain better ..